# How to debug or run locally GCP serverless application in nodejs?

Tags: debugging, google-cloud-platform, local, serverless

As this [link](https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline/issues/374), the serverless offline is only supporting to AWS. And I want to know that is there any library similar to serverless offline which support GCP or is there any other way of running locally? If there is a way please provide a reference.

Comment: There are several questions like this recently. What do you want to test in offline mode? Cloud Task and Metadata server aren't possible (or with old (outdated??) library that mock the calls).

Comment: I want to test API calls

Comment: API calls of what? Your application? Or the API calls from your application to Google Cloud?

Comment: my application. serverless functions' (endpoints) APIs

Answer (score 1):

You have the [Functions Framework](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs), which allows you to spin up a local development server for quick Cloud Functions testing, but AFAIK, there is nothing for emulating GCP's API Gateway locally